# How do I pass a variable from directive to a controller using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that is called in a directive html. I'd like to pass that object to the controller. How do I do that? Below is a copy of what I have so far

**wpGroup.html**

```
<button ng-click="hideGroup(item.id)">-</button>
```

**wp-group.js**

```
 scope:{hideGroup: &} //nothing else related to hideGroup or item.id
```

**wp-view.html**

```
 <data-wp-group data-item="childItem" data-hide-group="vm.hideGroup(vm.id)"/>
```

Comment: it's not clear from the single lines you posted from these files what you are trying to accomplish, or what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

`functions` in javascript are first class, they can be pass as arguments wherever you want.

if i understand correctly you want to pass that `hideGroup` function to a different controller and invoke it.

You can share the reference between the two , with some events handling (or better) using custom service.

```
.service('ShareDataService', function(){
 var data;
 this.setFn = function(fn){
  data = fn;
 }
 this.getFn = function(){
  return data;
 }
})
```

then in your directive inject the service and set the data.

```
ShareDataService.setFn(scope.hideGroup);
```

and get the reference in your controller;

```
var hideGroupFn = ShareDataService.getFn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question hoping that `data-wp-group` is your directive.

These should be modified,

**wp-group.js**

```
 scope:{dataHideGroup: &} //nothing else related to hideGroup or item.id
```

inside up-group.js,

```
scope.hideGroup = function(id){
  scope.dataHideGroup({"id":id});
 }
```

**wp-view.html**

```
 <data-wp-group data-item="childItem" data-hide-group="vm.hideGroup(id)"/>
```

Hope you understand what I said